# How to change pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ PACKAGE-NAME to pip install PACKAGE-NAME

Tags: python, windows, pip, pypi, python-packaging

I have uploaded my package to the https://test.pypi.org/ using [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). But, at the end, the installation works with `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ PACKAGE-NAME`. However, I aimed at installing the package using `pip install PACKAGE-NAME`.

Anybody knows how can I change it to work with `pip install PACKAGE-NAME`?

For more information, I have a `setup.py` file, which looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
from os import path


current_dir = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))


with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

with open(path.join(current_dir, 'requirements.txt'), 'r') as f:
    install_requires = f.read().split('\n')

setup(
      name='package name',
      version='0.0.1',
      author='author name',
      author_email='author's email',
      description='description',
      long_description=long_description,
      long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
      license='License',
      packages=['package name'],
      keywords='keywords',
      classifiers=[
              "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
              "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
              "Operating System :: OS Independent"
              ],
      python_requires='>=3.6'
      )
```

and I have also a `setup.cfg` file, which is:

```
[build_sphinx]
source-dir = docs
build-dir = docs/_build
all_files = 1

[upload_sphinx]
upload-dir = docs/_build/html

[easy_install]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue with my problem today. When you upload your package on https://test.pypi.org/, the installation using `pip` works with:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ PACKAGE-NAME
```

to be able to install the package with `pip install PACKAGE-NAME`, you should upload it on https://pypi.org/.

Therefore, I needed to walk through the steps in [the tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) for `pypi`, not for `test.pypi`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux/Mac try this:
In the user's home directory

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.pip
$ touch ~/.pip/pip.conf
```

Add this config in ~/.pip/pip.conf

```
[global]
index-url=https://test.pypi.org/simple/
trusted-host=test.pypi.org
```

Then run `pip install package-name`

It should now directly download from the test index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am on Windows. Does it work on Windows as well?

Comment: I have tried the same thing for Windows, but unfortunately it didn't work. Still I cannot install it with pip install package-name.

Comment: @MaryamBahrami try the configuration mentioned in this official documentation : https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration.